# XeLatex typeset the document with Segoe UI

Tags: fonts, xetex, sans-serif

I try to change the font of my document with `\setmainfont{Segoe UI}`. The point is that it should work on other machines also, without installing extra fonts. Latex packages are no problem.

I tried `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set sans serif font as default`, which has no effect on the math font.

Also `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}` did not had the desired effect.
Same for `\setmathfont{Fira Math}` (Fira math was not found).

What I would like it that a number in text (for example 5) looks the same in a math of `\SI` environment. At the moment it is not the case. I tried to use another font that would look like the same, but that did not work. In the best case I would like to not use another font, but to use Segoe UI for the whole document.

Comment: you appear to be using unicode-math so you need an OpenType math font (with an internal MATH table within the font data) so Segoe UI is not suitable

Comment: since you are assuming latex is on the machine, why not use a tex distributed font? latin modern math will be available as will FiraMath. Note xetex by default can only find these by _filename_ not using the internal font name.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I would like to use the tex distributed fonts, but I did not got it working with for exmaple FiraMath, it throws an error that the font is not found. Could you provide an working example with XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to use a tex provided OpenType sans serif with XeLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{FiraSans-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

One Two Three 123 $123 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3$

\end{document}
```

Comment: the digits are spaced diffeently here, but the text fira fonts have various font feature settings to control oldstyle or lining or tabular digits, so I suspect the tabular setting will do what you want.